# If an analytic function has an algebraic order $h$ at infinity then $\lim_{z\to\infty}z^{-h}f(z)$ is not zero nor is it infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume infinity is not an essential singularity of the analytic function $f$. Then how is $h$, the algebraic order of $f$ such that $\lim_{z\to\infty}z^{-h}f(z)$ is not zero nor is it infinity?

**p.s.** The nature of the singularity of $f(z)$ at infinity is by definition the same as that of $f(\frac1z)$ at zero.

The algebraic order at a non-essential singularity $a$ is the whole number $h$ such that $\lim_{z\to a}|z-a|^k|f(z)|=0$ for any $k<h$ and $\lim_{z\to a}|z-a|^k|f(z)|=\infty$ for any $k>h$.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. If $\infty$ is not an essential singularity, it is a pole or removable. So either $f$ has a zero of order $n$ at $\infty$, then the algebraic order is $n$, or it has a point of holomorphicity at $\infty$ and $f(\infty) \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, then the algebraic order is $0$, or it has a pole of order $k$ in $\infty$, then the algebraic order is $-k$.

Comment: Consider $f(z) = z^h$. Then $\lim_{z\to\infty} z^{-h}f(z) = 1$. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: My question is why $\lim_{z\to\infty}z^{-h}f(z)\not =0$ and $\lim_{z\to\infty}z^{-h}f(z)\not =\infty$. Here $h$ is the algebraic order of $f$ at infinity.